# Intuitive explanation for - Shreve Vol 1 Ch 3 Lemma 3.2.6

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value

I need help in getting a more intuitive understanding of this lemma 3.2.6 in Vol 1 of Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance:

[image: formula]

Here, in the context of multi-period binomial pricing model, Y is a random variable that depends only on the first m toin cosses, where m is greater than or equal to n. Z is the Radon Nikodym Derivative process such that

[image: formula2]

I understand the equation, and I can derive it mathematically by myself without any help too. Its just that I can't find an intuition behind it. Any kind of help would be great. Thanks !

Comment: I would love to have an answer to this one as well!